# Import Objective-c library into Swift App

Tags: swift

I'd like to use a statically compiled objective-c library (+ headers) in my Swift app. I've already defined my bridging header for the project but Xcode still can't find the header.

Here's what my project's hiearchy looks

```
PROJECT_DIRECTORY/
---SwiftApp
------SwiftApp-Bridging-Header.h
------SwiftApp.xcodeproj
------Other Swift files live here
---Objective-C_Dependencies
------SharedLibrary/
---------Public/SharedLibraryInclude.h
---------SharedLibrary.a
```

The contents of SwiftApp-Bridging-Header.h:

```
#import "SharedLibrary/SharedLibraryInclude.h"
```

Despite the SwiftApp's Build Setting's header search paths to include `$(SRCROOT)/../Objective-C_Dependencies/SharedLibrary/Public` and Swift Compiler - Search Paths's Import Path to also have the same value as above, xcode tells me that

```
SharedLibrary/SharedLibraryInclude.h can't be found.
```

What else should I configure for Swift to recognize my external includes?

Comment: Doesn't this make Swift look for your header in `SharedLibrary/Public/SharedLibrary/SharedLibraryInclude.h`? Is that what you intend? I did not see from your question where the header file actually is located.

Comment: I think it looks for the header in that location but based on the error, it doesn't seem like it's been found.

Comment: Can you try `#import "SharedLibraryInclude.h" instead?

Comment: I tried that it and same complaint. After trying a few more things, I'm certain that it's a path issue.

Comment: Can you try looking at the build log to see what the paths are passed into the swift compiler?